# How To Make .php form submit button two actions

Tags: php, forms, button, tabs, submit

Hello i want to make one form That Submits data to XXXXXXX and opens a new tab alongside with mydomain.com
Please Help Me To Get This..

```
<form action="XXXXXXXXXX" method="get" style="margin-top: 12px;">
        <label>
            <input type="text" name="user" value="" style="width: 100%" placeholder="Your Code Here" autocomplete="off" autofocus="" required>
        </label>
        <input type="submit" style="width: 84px;margin-top: 10px;" value="Submit" class="submit">
    </form>
```

Please Send me Some Details To Do This.. i Firstly Saw This on official-liker.net submit button..

Comment: Have you tried adding an onsubmit action to the form using JS? In this action you can open the new window and then perform the form submit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that you would need to use jQuery to submit the form using AJAX and in it's `success` callback via

> window.open(url,'_blank');

Comment: Thanks i found this answer from any another site!! thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<form action="XXXXXXXXXX" method="get" style="margin-top: 12px;" target=_blank>
    <label>
        <input type="text" name="user" value="" style="width: 100%" placeholder="Your Code
 Here" autocomplete="off" autofocus="" required>
    </label>

    <input type="submit" style="width: 84px;margin-top: 10px;" value="Submit"

   class="submit">
    </form>
```

The target attribute specifies a name or a keyword that indicates where to display the response that is received after submitting the form.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below

```
<form action="XXXXXXXXXX.php" method="get" target="_blank" style="margin-top: 12px;">
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for Javascript, you just have to add a `target="_blank"` attribute in your form tag.

```
  <form action="XXXXXXXXXX" method="get" style="margin-top: 12px;" target=_blank>
            <label>
                <input type="text" name="user" value="" style="width: 100%" placeholder="Your Code Here" autocomplete="off" autofocus="" required>
            </label>
            <input type="submit" style="width: 84px;margin-top: 10px;" value="Submit" class="submit">
        </form>
```

Following link will help:[HTML form target](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_target.asp)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get Redirected after the Post header("Location: http://www.example.com/") php function.
If you want to open alongside you can use JQuery.

```
<form>

   <input name="text2" type="text" id="text" />

<a class="className" href="#" name="save" id="saveButton">Save</A>

</form>
```

After that some JavaScript stuff:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#save").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.post("sendPhp.php", { textPost : $("#text").val()},
              function(html) {
                   //open a new window here
                   window.open("mydomain.com");
              }
    });
});
```